# Pixels intensity values between two lines

Tags: python, opencv

I have created an alghoritm that detects the edges of an extruded colagen casing and draws a centerline between these edges on an image. [Casing with a centerline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI4IH.png).

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/5.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.resize(img, (1500, 1200))

#ROI
fromCenter = False
r = cv2.selectROI(img, fromCenter)
imCrop = img[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]

#Operations on an image
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(imCrop,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(opening,(7,7),0)

edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 0,20)

#Edges localization, packing coords into a list
indices = np.where(edges != [0])
coordinates = list(zip(indices[1], indices[0]))
num = len(coordinates)

#Separating into top and bot edge
bot_cor = coordinates[:int(num/2)]
top_cor = coordinates[-int(num/2):]

#Converting to arrays, sorting
a, b = np.array(top_cor), np.array(bot_cor)
a, b = a[a[:,0].argsort()], b[b[:,0].argsort()]

#Edges approximation by a 5th degree polynomial
min_a_x, max_a_x = np.min(a[:,0]), np.max(a[:,0])
new_a_x = np.linspace(min_a_x, max_a_x, imCrop.shape[1])
a_coefs = np.polyfit(a[:,0],a[:,1], 5)
new_a_y = np.polyval(a_coefs, new_a_x)

min_b_x, max_b_x = np.min(b[:,0]), np.max(b[:,0])
new_b_x = np.linspace(min_b_x, max_b_x, imCrop.shape[1])
b_coefs = np.polyfit(b[:,0],b[:,1], 5)
new_b_y = np.polyval(b_coefs, new_b_x)

#Defining a centerline
midx = [np.average([new_a_x[i], new_b_x[i]], axis = 0) for i in range(imCrop.shape[1])]
midy = [np.average([new_a_y[i], new_b_y[i]], axis = 0) for i in range(imCrop.shape[1])]

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Cross section')
plt.xlabel('Length of the casing', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Width of the casing', fontsize=18)
plt.plot(new_a_x, new_a_y,c='black')
plt.plot(new_b_x, new_b_y,c='black')
plt.plot(midx, midy, '-', c='blue')
plt.show()

#Converting coords type to a list (plotting purposes)
coords = list(zip(midx, midy))
points = list(np.int_(coords))

mask = np.zeros((imCrop.shape[:2]), np.uint8)
mask = edges

#Plotting
for point in points:
    cv2.circle(mask, tuple(point), 1, (255,255,255), -1)

for point in points:
    cv2.circle(imCrop, tuple(point), 1, (255,255,255), -1)  

cv2.imshow('imCrop', imCrop)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now I would like to sum up the intensities of each pixel in a region between top edge and a centerline (same thing for a region between centerline and a bottom edge).

Is there any way to limit the ROI to the region between the detected edges and split it into two regions based on the calculated centerline?

Or is there any way to access the pixels which are contained between the edge and a centerline based on theirs coordinates?

(It's my very first post here, sorry in advance for all the mistakes)

Comment: if all images are very similar to your sample image, you probably can separate background and create two masks (for upper and lower part) and use them to isolate your ROI. Have you tried something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a somewhat naïve code to get masks for the upper and lower part. My code considers that the source image will be always like yours: with horizontal stripes.

After applying `Canny` I get this:

[image]

Then I run some loops through image array to fill unwanted areas of your image. This is done separately for upper and lower part, creating masks. The results are:

[image]

Then you can use this masks to sum only the elements you're interested in, using `cv.sumElems`.

```
import cv2 as cv

#open as grayscale image
src = cv.imread("colagen.png",cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# apply canny and find contours
threshold = 100
canny_output = cv.Canny(src, threshold, threshold * 2)

# find mask for upper part
mask1 = canny_output.copy()
x, y = canny_output.shape
area = 0
for j in range(y):
    area = 0
    for i in range(x):
        if area == 0:
            if mask1[i][j] > 0:
                area = 1
                continue
            else: 
                mask1[i][j] = 255
        elif area == 1:
            if mask1[i][j] > 0:
                area = 2
            else: 
                continue
        else:
            mask1[i][j] = 255
mask1 = cv.bitwise_not(mask1)

# find mask for lower part         
mask2 = canny_output.copy()
x, y = canny_output.shape
area = 0
for j in range(y):
    area = 0
    for i in range(x):
        if area == 0:
            if mask2[-i][j] > 0:
                area = 1
                continue
            else: 
                mask2[-i][j] = 255
        elif area == 1:
            if mask2[-i][j] > 0:
                area = 2
            else: 
                continue
        else:
            mask2[-i][j] = 255
mask2 = cv.bitwise_not(mask2)

# apply masks and calculate sum of elements in upper and lower part
sums = [0,0]
(sums[0],_,_,_) = cv.sumElems(cv.bitwise_and(src,mask1))
(sums[1],_,_,_) = cv.sumElems(cv.bitwise_and(src,mask2))

cv.imshow('src',src)
cv.imshow('canny',canny_output)
cv.imshow('mask1',mask1)
cv.imshow('mask2',mask2)
cv.imshow('masked1',cv.bitwise_and(src,mask1))
cv.imshow('masked2',cv.bitwise_and(src,mask2))
cv.waitKey()
```

#### Alternatives...

Probably there exist some function that fill the areas of the Canny result. I tried `cv.fillPoly` and `cv.floodFill`, but didn't manage to make them work easily... But maybe someone else can help you with that...

#### Edit

Found another way to get the masks with a cleaner code. Using numpy `np.add.accumulate` then `np.clip`, and then a modulo operation:

```
# first divide canny_output by 255 to get 0's and 1's, then perform
# an accumulate addition for each column. Thus you'll get +1 for every
# line, "painting" areas with 1, 2, 3...
a = np.add.accumulate(canny_output/255,0)
# clip values: anything greater than 2 becomes 2
a = np.clip(a, 0, 2)
# performe a modulo, to get areas alternating with 0 or 1; then multiply by 255
a = a%2 * 255
# convert to uint8
mask1 = cv.convertScaleAbs(a)

# to get mask2 (the lower mask) flip the array then do the same as above
a = np.add.accumulate(np.flip(canny_output,0)/255,0)
a = np.clip(a, 0, 2)
a = a%2 * 255
mask2 = cv.convertScaleAbs(np.flip(a,0))
```

This returns *almost* the same result. The border of the mask is a little bit different...

Comment: First solution works like a charm, thank you! I'll try to apply the `np.add.accumulate` method as well.